# When to use "$and" operator in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a query in mongodb where I have to filter all the cities in **India** with longitude between 75 and 80, I have this working expression for that

```
{"$match":{"country":"India","lon":{"$gt":75},"lon":{"$lt":80}}},
```

This expression is working fine, However while going through the documentation of $and, I noticed that

> Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

So according to the documentation, it should not work fine,since I have lon field appearing multiple time but it is working as expected. So can anyone explain to me what scenario documentation is referring to where $and will be required?

Comment: By the way, `{"$match":{"country":"India","lon":{"$gt":75},"lon":{"$lt":80}}}` is just the same as `{"$match":{"country":"India","lon":{"$gt":75, "$lt":80}}}`

Comment: @chridam true, I tried that as well. But I wanted to check the implicit $and of the mongodb and according to the documentation, my db in the question should not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conclusion that your query is "working fine" isn't right. Only one of those `lon` fields will actually be used by the query; probably the second one. So the query will *execute* fine, but the docs won't be correctly filtered.

Proof at the python prompt:

```py
>>> q = {"$match":{"country":"India","lon":{"$gt":75},"lon":{"$lt":80}}}
>>> q
{'$match': {'country': 'India', 'lon': {'$lt': 80}}}
```

The rule to follow is that you should only use `$and` when you have multiple conditions to use for the same key, and you can't combine them into a single object.

As chidham notes, your query should be constructed to combine the two `lon` conditions as:

```py
{"$match": {"country": "India", "lon": {"$gt": 75, "$lt": 80}}}
```

Comment: What I meant was I ran that query and it was accepted as a correct result. Since it is online quiz, I don't know what is the correct output returned. So in your opinion my query won't give me the value between 75 and 80, because of the second key overriding the first one?

Comment: Correct, only the `$lt` part gets used.

Comment: watch this video by MongoDB for more clear explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6AWI2sVs3I (it's part of M001 Course)

Comment: Is there a reason why it works that way ? I'm currently watching the M001 course and she explains when to use explicit $and but not why